# Power BI Report Builder tabular model connection query size limit issue

Tags: connection-string, dax, reportbuilder3.0, ssas-tabular, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am having a problem in Power BI Report Builder where I am running a memory intensive DAX query which cannot be simplified.
When executing the query in query designer I get the following error:
[image: Error Message]

Upon research I cannot find where to change this setting, the closest I have come is this property but it does not change the size limit: DbpropMsmdRequestMemoryLimit

Does anyone know how to change this property or is this even the correct correct property to be changing?

Comment: are you sure your query cannot be simplified? can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

There are settings on the Azure analysis server, by default the query size limit is set to 20% of the server capacity, this can be increased or decreased and it solved my problem.